# Show Image selected from JFileChooser in a set sized JPanel (image must be re-scaled)

Tags: java, image, jpanel, jfilechooser

I am trying to fit an image in a set sized JPanel (picture panel--- black border line) (MUST FIT THE JPANEl "Picture panel"). When i click the upload button, i am able to see the JFilechooser in a new JFrame and select the picture i want, however after the 'open' button click nothing happens.

```
import classes.BackgroundPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Upload");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
        final JFrame imageFrame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        final Test_Image t = new Test_Image();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel picturePanel = new JPanel();
     //  chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
          Dimension d = new Dimension(1261, 765);
          Dimension d2 = new Dimension(1300, 900);
          picturePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
          panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
          Dimension d3 = new Dimension(343, 247);
          picturePanel.setSize(d3);
            //picturePanel.setSize(d);
          panel.add(button);
          panel.setSize(d3);


        //panel.setVisible(true);
       //panel.add(picturePanel);

       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(chooser.showOpenDialog(imageFrame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    try {
                        Image bi = ImageIO.read(
                        chooser.getSelectedFile());
                        BackgroundPanel bp = new BackgroundPanel(bi);
                        if (bi != null)
                        bp.setImage(bi);
                        else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imageFrame,
                        "File is not an image!");
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imageFrame,
                        "Error Reading File!");
}                
                }                              

            }
        });      


      frame.setSize(d2);
      frame.add(picturePanel).setLocation(100, 100);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I assume that you draw your image in the BackgroundPanel and that you use the appropriate drawImage overload to rescale it as needed -- correct (it would be nice to show the code for BackgroundPanel)? Where do you add your BackgroundPanel, bp, to the picturePanel or to anything?

Comment: @Nivas, It appears that [`BackgroundPanel`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) is a custom class created by @camickr.

Comment: @HoverCraft, I am trying to add the selected image to the BackGroundPanel 'bp' and add that panel to fit my picture panel which has a set size.

Comment: @Warz: There are still unanswered questions from my comment. Please see the answer I've posted below for more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundPanel bp = new BackgroundPanel(bi);
```

You don't add the BackgroundPane to the frame anywhere. The basic code for dynamically adding components is:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

If you have already added the BackgroundPanel to the frame then you should be able to just invoke the setImage() method on the panel. So now you need to change your code to use ImageIO.read(...) to read in the image after you've selected the path from the file chooser.

Comment: do i add the background panel after the button action performed, because i cant access bp if i am not inside the button action listener method?

Comment: You don't have to use an annonymous inner class for your listener. You can create a separate ActionListener class and pass in a reference to the BackgroundPanel when you create the class. Now your listener has access to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I don't see anywhere where you add the BackgroundPanel to the picturePanel JPanel. You will need to set the picturePanel's layout to BorderLayout and then add the BackgroundPanel, bp to the picturePanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, and then call revalidate and repaint as camickr shows you.

We also don't see the code for your BackgroundPanel class even though we've requested it. Again, I hope that you're drawing the image in its paintComponent method and using the proper drawImage overload, but til you show the code, we won't know for sure.

Comment: the background panel class is here (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). Thanks for the help. Can i do all of those mentioned steps right inside my button click action event method?

Comment: @Warz: best to try it and find out.

Comment: i have got the image correctly set in the background panel 'bp' and also added bp to my picturePanel as a component using the BorderLayout.Center for a position and then called picturePanel.revalidate and repaint afterwards but still unable to view the image. I have print statements showing the path is found and an image size is there.